# Start Node.js App on Server Boot/Restart

Tags: node.js, centos

I have no idea how to start my node.js app on server restart/server boot. The only thing I know is that if I do 'npm start' my application starts but I need this to be automatic and running constantly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use pm2 or forever and then create a script to load the application. pm2 is well documented and has a helper to create an init script. blog.hazrulnizam.com/create-init-script-centos-6 can help you to create the init script too. Another option is to use supervisor.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
nohup `npm start` &
```

**OR**

read the documentation about forever and pm2 module , these are easiest way to start your application at backend process

Comment: nohup is just not reliable choice. Ideally, you'll need to log the process, pm2 is better.